# Getting Current Location using Parse SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, location

I'm trying to get the current location of the user using the build in geoPointForCurrentLocation method. I try to set the geoPoint in a custom field i created in my User class called location and then attempt to save it using the saveInBackground method.

```
[PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground: ^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {
    if (!error)
    {                
        [[PFUser currentUser] setObject: geoPoint forKey: @"location"];                
        [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];                
    }            
}];
```

No errors are thrown but the user's location is not saved to the database.

Edit:

My viewDidLoad method looks like this:

self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

```
if ([self.locationManager
    respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
```

}

and I set the info.plist key for when in use authorization.

Comment: Have you requested location access and added the permission strings to your info.plist?

Comment: No I don't get it in either my simulator or on my phone.

Comment: I checked the privacy setting and Never and Always (the only two options) were both unchecked so I checked Always and then tried again with no results. In info.plist I have NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in the key column but the Value column is blank.

Comment: The value for that key needs to be a string that is displayed to the user that explains why you want to use their location

Comment: Okay I added a value but the prompt is still a no show. Also I added a NSLog test inside the currentLocation block and it did not fire so i'm assuming i'm doing something wrong with regards to the block.

Comment: delete the app so that the privacy settings are reset and try again

Comment: I did, still no prompt.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and confirm that you are calling `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`

Comment: Yes, it breaks at the  requestWhenInUseAuthorization  call.

Comment: Okay figured it out, I didn't mark my implementation file with <CLLocationManagerDelegate>. Thank you for the help Paul.

Answer (score 0):

Did not mark my implementation file with CLLocationManagerDelegate.